# ItemAdd Event on Redemption Folder - how to use properly with Console Application

Tags: outlook-redemption

I have a .Net Console Application that emails documents using Redemption with Outlook. I attach the "Items.ItemAdd" event to the relevant folder. The event never fires.

But in my test harness which is a WPF application, using the same method and the same references etc, it does work.

Does the event actually work in a console app? Is there an example of the correct way, or of an alternate way?

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to run the Windows message loop for the events to work.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for that hint. I tried various things and eventually it seems to work as below:

```
DispatcherOperation op = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { SomeMethod(someArgs); }));
DispatcherOperationStatus status = op.Status;
while (status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed && status != DispatcherOperationStatus.Aborted)
{
    status = op.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
    if (status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Completed || status == DispatcherOperationStatus.Aborted)
    {
        // do your final code
    }
}
```